# "Customizing" InputMismatchExceptions

Tags: java, try-catch, inputmismatchexception

I want the user to input a string of letters representing grades (for example, ABEDCBA, etc.).

Is there a way to "customize" an InputMismatchException so that when a letter after E is entered, it throws that exception? Or should this case be handled with something other than InputMismatchException? Ideally I'd like the exception to catch any letters after E and any numbers/symbols as well. Is that possible? New programmer here, so thanks for your help!

```
do {
         try
         {
            System.out.print ("Please type the grades: ");
            String answerKey = Integer.toString(System.in.read());      
            exc = false; 
         }

         catch (InputMismatchException ime)
         {
            System.out.println ("You may only enter A, B, C, D, or E.");           
         }
} while (exc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should match using regexp for letters/symbols other than A,B,C,D, and E:
And you don't need to catch InputMismatchException it doesn't make sense.

```
System.out.print ("Please type the grades: ");
String regex = "\\b[A-E]+\\b";
if(!Integer.toString(System.in.read()).matches(regex))
{
   System.out.println ("You may only enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
}
```